# How to set value of button from model?

Tags: knockout.js

I have the following Knockout model:

```
var searchButtonModel = {
    name: 'Name',
    search: function () {
        //do something
    }
}
```

and the template:

```
<button data-bind="click: search"></button>
```

I want to value of model name property('Name') in value property of button. Could I do it?

Comment: I'm confused. Do you just want `<button data-bind="text: name, click: search"></button>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<button data-bind="click: search,text:name"></button>
```